# Simple example of a perfect complex not isomorphic to a strictly perfect complex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I'm looking for the simplest possible example (one that's easy to remember) for the situation described in the title. More precisely I'm looking for the following example:

A (probably has to be singular) algebraic surface $X$ (2-dimensional, reduced, integral, finite type over $k$ algebraically closed) and a complex of coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ on $X$ whose image in $D(X)$ is perfect but not quasi-isomorphic to a strictly perfect complex. (Bonus points for a simple toric surface example).

---

Definitions:

1. A **strictly perfect** complex is an object in the derived category $D(X)$ isomorphic to a bounded complex of vector bundles
2. A **perfect complex** is an object in the derived category $M \in D(X)$ satisfying that for every point $x \in X$ there's a open zariski neighborhood $x \in U$ over which $M_U \in D(U)$ is perfect ("locally strictly perfect").

Comment: If I recall correctly you need a scheme without an ample family of line bundles, and this rules out all quasi-projective examples.

Comment: I am pretty sure that on every quasi-projective scheme over a field, e.g., your curve above, every perfect object is strictly perfect.  This should be in SGA 6, but you might first look in Thomason-Trobaugh.

Comment: oh shoot. Then let me revise.

Comment: Any such example will fail to have the "resolution property".  If memory serves, there is an example of a (non-separated) scheme failing the resolution property in the article of Edidin, Hassett, Kresch, and Vistoli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is silly to post this as an answer.  My answer to your other question also answers this question. 
 [Can the homological dimension of a coherent sheaf explode along a formal deformation? (is the resolution property hereditary for formal deformations?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269776/can-the-homological-dimension-of-a-coherent-sheaf-explode-along-a-formal-deforma/269797#269797) 
That example is smooth, integral, and 2-dimensional over a field.  However, it is not separated.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this! I was very worried about this issue once. Now that I know that there's a dichotomy (ala the other question) I'm much more relaxed.