# Perfect complexes on stacks are strict?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

As mentioned in the comments of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259031/simple-example-of-a-perfect-complex-not-isomorphic-to-a-strictly-perfect-complex), on a quasiprojective scheme over a field, every perfect complex is *globally* a complex of vector bundles.

I have some question about the extension of this to stacks:

1. Is this true $G$ equivariantly? i.e. is it true for $X/G$ where $X$ is quasiprojective?
2. As a slight extension of this, is this true for $\text{Bun}_G(X)$ where $X$ is a curve?

(and 3. it would be nice to have a modern reference to the original question about quasiprojective schemes, which I've not actually been able to find yet).

Comment: Yes, 1 is true, at least for bounded perfect complexes.  The key point is that for every perfect complex of amplitude $[a,b]$, for a $G$-equivariant complex of vector bundles of amplitude $[a+1,b]$ and a $G$-equivariant morphism from that complex to the original complex that is a quasi-isomorphism on the "good truncations" $\tau_{>a}$, the cone is a perfect complex concentrated in one degree, which then has a $G$-equivariant homology sheaf that is a $G$-equivariant vector bundle.  So now you can "adjoin" this to the $G$-equivariant complex of vector bundles.  Surely there is a reference . . .